# select from v$lock in powershell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

I try to run this fragment (as sys/ as sysdba):

```
    try{
$conn = New-Object Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.ConnectionString= $connectionString
$conn.open();
$q =  "select * from v$lock ";    
$reader = (new-Object Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($q,$conn)).ExecuteScalar();
Write-Host $reader 

$conn.close()
} catch {

 Write-Host ( $_.Exception.Message )
}
```

On toad I can select v$lock, but in my script I have ansver like

```
    Exception calling "ExecuteScalar" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [42S02] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

where is the cause of the problem?

Comment: The problem here is either with the user - if that user does't have the rights to select from this table or the escaping of the `$` symbol. I am not sure how ps handles this character. In unix shell we have to escape it, so it would be `v\$lock`.

Comment: thank You! You have right, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Powershell thinks that you are referring to variable `$lock` on this statement instead of string literial `v$lock`:

```
$q =  "select * from v$lock ";
```

You got to either escape the `$` symbol with a backtick `` ` `` or use single quotes that don't expand variables. What's more, idiomatic Powershell doesn't use semicolon for statement terminators. Like so,

```
$q =  'select * from v$lock '  # Single quotes don't expand variables
$q =  "select * from v`$lock " # Backtick escapes $ not to be a variable symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape spesial characters or use a literal string. `$` is used for variables.

Try

```
$q =  "select * from v`$lock"
```

Or

```
$q =  'select * from v$lock'
```